# Unbold maths in thmbox title?

Tags: bold, boldmath, customize, thmbox

So I've been trying to use thmbox to add some interest to my undergrad report, but I didn't like the default style and so I'm trying to adjust it. I've got it mostly how I want, except any maths in the titles still show as bold, even though I have changed the title style using `\mdseries`.

This is what I've done in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\newtheorem[L]{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem[L]{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem[L]{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem[L]{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem[L]{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem[S]{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\thmboxoptions{
leftmargin = 4.5pt, 
thickness = 0.3pt,
bodystyle = \itshape\noindent,
titlestyle = \hspace{0.15cm}-\hspace{0.15cm}(\mdseries{#1})
}
```

And using it like so:

```
\begin{definition}[The Free Group on Two Generators, $F_2$]       
The free group on two generators, $F_2$ is a free group over a set with two elements (generators), $S = \{a,b\}$, containing all reduced words that can be formed by concatenating elements of $\{ a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}\}$. The identity is the empty word, denoted $e$.
\end{definition}
```

Gives:
[image]

I don't want $F_2$ to be bold!

Also, if anyone could help me make it so that the boxes fully enclose the content that would be a bonus! This is my ideal but I'm also happy with how it is if not! (also I'm not very experienced with LaTeX so please try and give me simple solutions if possible!)

Comment: You also have to change `headstyle`. And please focus to one question.

Comment: What would I change it to? The documentation says the default is `\bfseries\boldmath#1 #2` where #1 represents the environment name (Definition) and #2 represents the number (1.4). I want both of these to be bold. It's the maths in the title I don't want to be bold.

Comment: Sorry, but without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) I have nothing to test and reproduce your problem. But IMHO the `\boldmath` causes the bold math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `headstyle` for the job. Using `\textbf` avoids the boldface to propagate. You need it, because the package has, by default, `\bfseries\boldmath`.

I'd use an en-dash rather than a hyphen and upright parentheses in the body. Actually, definitions are commonly typeset in upright type, reserving emphasis for the defined concept.

If you want that the left bar is flush with the left margin, the correct space is 4.3pt and you need also that on the right. Why? Because of a bug in the `thmbox` package: you *always* get an overfull by 4.3pt otherwise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmbox}

\newtheorem[L]{definition}{Definition}[section]

\thmboxoptions{
  leftmargin = 4.3pt,
  rightmargin= 4.3pt,% <--- or you get an overfull of 4.3pt
  thickness = 0.3pt,
  bodystyle = \itshape\noindent,
  titlestyle = \ --\ (#1),
  headstyle = \textbf{#1 #2},
}

\newcommand{\itp}[1]{\textup{(}#1\textup{)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[The Free Group on Two Generators, $F_2$]
The free group on two generators, $F_2$ is a free group over a set with two
elements \itp{generators}, $S = \{a,b\}$, containing all reduced words that
can be formed by concatenating elements of $\{a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}\}$. The
identity is the empty word, denoted $e$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, definitions are commonly typeset in upright type, reserving emphasis for the defined concept. However it's a stylistic decision.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmbox}

\newtheorem[L]{definition}{Definition}[section]

\thmboxoptions{
  leftmargin = 4.3pt,
  rightmargin= 4.3pt,% <--- or you get an overfull of 4.3pt
  thickness = 0.3pt,
  bodystyle = \upshape\noindent,
  titlestyle = \ --\ (#1),
  headstyle = \textbf{#1 #2},
}

\newcommand{\itp}[1]{\textup{(}#1\textup{)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[The Free Group on Two Generators, $F_2$]
The \emph{free group on two generators}, $F_2$ is a free group over a set with two 
elements (generators), $S = \{a,b\}$, containing all reduced words that 
can be formed by concatenating elements of $\{a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}\}$. The 
identity is the empty word, denoted $e$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As hinted at in the comments, simply remove the `\boldmath` switch in the `headstyle` key. Note that `\mdseries` is a switch, not a command that takes an argument, so your use of `\mdseries{#1}` in `titlestyle` can just be `\mdseries #1`. As egreg mentions in the comments, you should also put `\mdseries` before `(` so the first parentheses is not bold.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmbox}

\newtheorem[L]{definition}{Definition}[section]

\thmboxoptions{
  leftmargin = 4.5pt, 
  thickness = 0.3pt,
  bodystyle = \itshape\noindent,
  titlestyle = \hspace{0.15cm}-\hspace{0.15cm}\mdseries(#1),
  headstyle = \bfseries#1 #2,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[The Free Group on Two Generators, $F_2$]       
The free group on two generators, $F_2$ is a free group over a set with two elements (generators), $S = \{a,b\}$, containing all reduced words that can be formed by concatenating elements of $\{ a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}\}$. The identity is the empty word, denoted $e$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: definition]

Comment: You also want `\mdseries` ***before*** `(`.

Comment: @egreg Ah thanks, fixed